# File lines concatenation

Tags: c

i have a method that is supposed to print file lines concatenated with other file lines, basically what i wanted to is is that if we have a file1 with this data

```
111100000
111001000
111000100
```

and file2 with this data

```
0
```

it supposed to returns 1+file1_lines+file2_lines so for this one it should returns

```
11111000000
11110010000
11110001000
```

Here is what I tried to do so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAILLE_MAX 10000


void assemblage_fichier(const char *file1, const char *file2){
    FILE *fichier1, *fichier2;
    fichier1 = fopen(file1, "r");
    fichier2 = fopen(file2, "r");
    char c[TAILLE_MAX], c2[TAILLE_MAX];
    
    if(!fichier1 || !fichier2){
        printf("cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    while (fgets(c, sizeof(c), fichier1) && fgets(c2, sizeof(c2), fichier2))
    {
        printf("1%s%s\n", c, c2);
    }
    
    fclose(fichier1);
    fclose(fichier2);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    assemblage_fichier(argv[1], argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

by the way my code returns:

```
11111000000
```

so it does the job for only one line.

Comment: sorry for my English :p

Comment: This is going to fail badly if argc < 2.

Comment: @jarmod the code is not completed yet so i didn't take care of everything

Comment: `fgets()` keeps the newline. You want to get rid of it before adding the final character: `c[strcspn(c, "\n")] = 0; printf("1%s%c\n", c, *c2);`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, thats what i thought is there an other way to do it?, i am new to c language so there is a ton of things i don't know yet.

Comment: @Sid-Ali Sorry, my comment was wrong. Looks like you *do* want to read the lines in parallel

Comment: @EugeneSh.Yes, that's what i tried to do the only this that i don't get is why my code does the job for only one line and then stops!

Comment: your second file has as many lines as the first? Your code implies it should! Otherwise remove the reading from second file from the loop (to read once only).

Comment: @pmg basically in python double for loops in two files lines reads first file line then all of the second file lines then moves to file1 second lines and does the same job, i dont know how t do that in c

Comment: Please show a very simple example of your two files (3-4 lines maximum) and properly formatted along with the expected output.

Comment: So you are reading the same complete file (I get it; it's only 1 line of 1 char) over and over and over as many times as there are lines in first file? May want to redo your Python too :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky juste added a pic of it.

Comment: @Sid-Ali And what if file2 has multiple lines? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets(c, sizeof(c), fichier1) && fgets(c2, sizeof(c2), fichier2)` will only evaluate to true if and only if both `fgets(c, sizeof(c), fichier1)` and `fgets(c2, sizeof(c2), fichier2)` are successful. However, since `fichier2` only has 1 line, `fgets(c2, sizeof(c2), fichier2)` returns NULL after the first iteration (since it reaches the end of the file).
From the fgets() man page:

> fgets() returns s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file
> occurs while no characters have been read.

That is why you see only one line being printed.

> basically in python double for loops in two files lines reads first
> file line then all of the second file lines then moves to file1 second
> lines and does the same job, i dont know how t do that in c

Well, nested loops exist in C as well.
Try changing this section of your code:

```
while (fgets(c, sizeof(c), fichier1) && fgets(c2, sizeof(c2), fichier2))
    {
        printf("1%s%s\n", c, c2);
    }
```

to something like this (the comments in the code point out the changes I've made):

```
while (fgets(c, sizeof(c), fichier1)){ //read one line from fichier1 at a time
    c[strcspn(c, "\n")] = 0; //for removing the newline as suggested by pmg
    while (fgets(c2, sizeof(c2), fichier2)){ //this loop reads from fichier2 until it reaches the end of the file
        printf("1%s%s\n", c, c2);
    }
    rewind(fichier2); //for changing the file position indicator for fichier2 to the beginning of the file since the file position indicator is at the end of fichier2 when the loop ends
 }
```

Comment: Finally, Thank you so much its really helping me getting into this language

Comment: @Sid-Ali You're welcome. You might also like to read the explanation I added as to why your code wasn't working.

Comment: Just a thought....shouldn't the code accommodate for files created on, say , Windows?.....I mean the "newline" character of such files would be represented by "\r\n".....Since just the '\n' character is being checked,the result outputted by the code would be erroneous when working with such files.

Comment: @LilyAB It should, yes, but that wasn't the OP's actual question.

Comment: @LilyAB even though the Windows representation of newline on disk is `"\r\n"`, when a file is opened in **text mode** (no `'b'` in the access mode of `fopen()`) the `"\r\n"` gets translated automatically to `"\n"` for input (and `"\n"` gets translated to `"\r\n"` for output).

Comment: @pmg I think they're talking about reading files created on Windows on a different OS.

Comment: @pmg..I do get that C converts the "carriage return" and "linefeed" to newline on input and back again on output.
What I was pointing out was that the solution provided did not accommodate for working with such files, even on Unix based OSes.
I mean, on Linux, working with a text file created on Windows, the code will not produce the expected results.